# Field data type / validations questions

Tags: database, validation, field

I have few questions on what data types to use and how to define some fields from my site. My current schema is in MySQL but in process of changing to PostregSQL.

1. First & Last name -> Since I have multi-lang, tables all support UTF-8, but do i need to declare them as nvarchar in-case a user enters a Chinese name? If so, how do i enforce field validation if it is set to accept alphabets only as i assume those are English alphabets and not validating for valid chinese or arabic alphabets? And i don't think PostregSQL supports nvarchar anyways?
2. To store current time line - > Example I work in company A from Jan 2009 to Present. So i assume there will be 3 field for this: timeline_to, timeline_from, time_line present where to & from are month/year varchars and present is just a flag to set the current date?
3. User passwords. i am using SHA 256 + salting. so i have 2 fields declared as follows:
   password_hash - varchar (64)
   password_salt-  varchar (64)
   Does this work if the user password needs to be between 8 and 32 chars long?
4. birth time -> I need to record birth time for the application to calculate some astrological values. so that means hour, minute and am/pm. So best to store these are 3 separate single select lists with varchar or use a time data type in the back end and allow users to use single select list in front end?
5. Lastly for birth month and year only, are these int or varchar if i store them in separate rows? They all have primary keys of int for reporting purposes so int makes more sense? or should i store them in 1 field only as date type?

Answer (score 1):

1. NCHAR, not NVARCHAR.

   - Never make anything variable that you can make fixed; it is an added burden to pack/unpack on every access.  Which means never, ever use var for indexed columns, you will have a very sluggish index.  Disk space is cheap these days.
   - you need a `Language` column at the `Person` level that tells you what language to use in your various parsing and validation requirements.
2. Let's say you have `Person, Employer`, and `Employment` tables.  The columns you discuss are in `Employment`.

   - you need a StartDate column and EndDate column, they are DATETIME datatype.
   - You do not need "present" as a separate column. "Present" is always the value of the newest `Employment` row, unless set to something different.  Set a Default of the highest date the db can handle, eg. 9999-12-31; which can be overridden by an explicit entry.
3. No.  You only need one CHAR(256) column.  Hank has explained it.
4. For any component of a date or time, use the DATETIME datatype.  That is what it is there for.  The database handles it consistently, and indexes it perfectly.  You perform DATE arithmetic on it, using db various functions().  And you avoid all the problems of coding it as INTs, etc (no invalid dates or times allowed).
5. BirthDateTime is one DATETIME column.

Answer (score 0):

1. I have no idea, never dealt with that field much.
2. You might consider allowing NULL here and using it as a special meaning for Present.  If your application logic sees a non-null start date and a null end date, you can infer this.  If they are both NULL, then no information can be inferred.
3. Since you're hashing, you'll always get a 256-bit hex string as the output no matter what the input is, so yes, 8-32 character passwords will all work.
4. Use a DATETIME in the backend.  You can do things like MONTH() to extract the parts right in your SQL syntax.  Of course, you'll have to format the date just right for SQL to accept it, but that's not too hard.
5. Again, all extractable with the DATETIME functions in SQL.

Comment: for 2, i can't. I still need to store the start/end date/time because people will be searching for others who are working in company X between say jan 08 and feb 09, so need to maintain both start/end dates, which is fine. i run into the issue with exiting users who are currently active because they have no fixed end date, it is always current so cant store any date in the DB for that.